# How do I get an input function to work whilst another code is running (using multiprocessing)?

Tags: python, input, multiprocessing

I can't get this code to run an input whilst another block of code is running. I want to know if there are any workarounds, my code is as follows.

```
import multiprocessing
def test1():
    input('hello')
def test2():
    a=True
    while a == True:
        b = 5
if __name__ == "__main__":
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=test1)
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=test2)
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
```

When the code is run I get an EOF error which apparently happens when the input function is interrupted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have the main process create a daemon `thread` responsible for doing the `input` in conjunction with creating the greatly under-utilized full duplex `Pipe` which provides two two-way communication `Connection` instances. For simplicity the following demo just creates one `Process` instance that loops doing `input` requests echoing the response until the user enters 'quit':

```py
import multiprocessing
import threading

def test1(conn):
    while True:
        conn.send('Please enter a value: ')
        s = conn.recv()
        if s == 'quit':
            break
        print(f'You entered: "{s}"')

def inputter(conn):
    while True:
        # The contents of the request is the prompt to be used:
        prompt = conn.recv()
        conn.send(input(prompt))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    conn1, conn2 = multiprocessing.Pipe(duplex=True)
    t = threading.Thread(target=inputter, args=(conn1,), daemon=True)
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=test1, args=(conn2,))
    t.start()
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

Answer (score 1):

That's not all of your code, because it doesn't show the multiprocessing.  However, the issue is that only the main process can interact with the console.  The other processes do not have a stdin.  You can use a Queue to communicate with the main process if you need to, but in general you want the secondary processes to be pretty much standalone.

Comment: yes, you are right sorry slipped my mind, I've edited my code. How do I make a queue? Also thanks for responding this is your second time you are a life saver and respond within seconds. @TimRoberts

Comment: The documentation page describes using a queue (https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html).  That will require that you think about your structure.  One process shoves something in one end, and another process pulls stuff from the other end.  Inter-process communication is not trivial.

Comment: Thank you very much I will look into it. @TimRoberts